# How to add horizontal scroll for flex box container?

Tags: html, css

I'm using flexbox to create a slider with horizontal slider in HTML. but with this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
.container{
  width: 425px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.container div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: teal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

all `div` elements get auto `width` and has not horizontal scroll that `container` box.

Comment: Flex children need a `flex` property to dictate how they behave, otherwise it will default to what you're seeing. `flex: 100px 0 0;` would work, although at that point you're not really using a flexbox, you just have a standard `div` with elements side-by-side...

Answer (score 2):

You can add `min-width` to your flex children to force keeping the desired width.

```css
.container div {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
.container{
  width: 425px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.container div{
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: teal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```